# Overwritten Data using SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite to access a local database. The table looks as follows:

`FrameIndex  FrameName     Bus    NoMinorFrames MinorFrameTime  TotalTime
   1        Bus_Frame_1   BUS-1         8            20           160 
   2        Bus_Frame_2   BUS-2         8            20           160 
   3        Bus_Frame_3   BUS-3         8            20           160 
   4        Bus_Frame_4   BUS-4         8            20           160 
   5        Bus_Frame_5   BUS-5         8            20           160`

I am trying to write a wrapper class so that every query would return a vector of all the records. In order to do this I am passing a reference of my class as an argument to `sqlite_exec()`

This is the header file for my wrapper class

```
class Database{
public:
    Database(const char*);
    int fnQueryExec(const char*);
    void fnClose();
    char* fnGetLastError();
    vector<char*> Data;
    //vector<vector<char*> > m_vectData;
    vector<char*> m_vectData;   //For testing purposes I am storing only second column.
    int Count;
    int  m_nCount;

private:
    sqlite3 *db;
    bool fnFileExists(const char*);
    bool m_bDatabaseStatus;
    char *m_SQLError;

};
```

And this is the callback function:

```
static int callback(void* object, int count, char **data, char **columns){
    Database* db= static_cast<Database*>(object);
    char* temp;
    temp = data[1];
    db->m_vectData.push_back(temp);
    db->m_nCount = count;
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is when I then print out the contents of the vector, this is the output:

`Row 1:  Bus_Frame_5
  Row 2:  Bus_Frame_5
  Row 3:  Bus_Frame_5
  Row 4:  Bus_Frame_5
  Row 5:  Bus_Frame_5`

Somehow pushing the data into the vector changes all the previous elements of the vector. I have tested this with a regular `char**` array instead of a vector with the same result. Even passing the reference of the vector alone causes the same issue.

```
vector<char*> *vect = static_cast<vector<char*>* >(object);
char* temp = data[1];
vect->push_back(temp);
for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex<vect->size(); nIndex++)
    printf("Data %s ", (*vect)[nIndex]);
printf("\n");
```

> Data Bus_Frame_1
>
> Data Bus_Frame_2
>   Data Bus_Frame_2
>
> Data Bus_Frame_3
>   Data Bus_Frame_3
>   Data Bus_Frame_3
>
> Data Bus_Frame_4
>   Data Bus_Frame_4
>   Data Bus_Frame_4
>   Data Bus_Frame_4
>
> Data Bus_Frame_5
>   Data Bus_Frame_5
>   Data Bus_Frame_5
>   Data Bus_Frame_5
>   Data Bus_Frame_5

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Use a vector of std::strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are copying the the same **pointer** value (or memory address if you like) data[1] into m_vectData each time. Therefore when you dump m_vectData, it shows the data currently at that memory address five times. One way to get this working would be to make m_vectData a vector of std::string instead.